# Iterating over a dataframe and plotting sections of the dataframe on the same plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm looping through a dataframe with clusters of entries and I want to plot each iteration of the dataframe slice.

I've tried using `ax = plot(iter 1)` with `ax = ax` for plotting "iter 2" but that doesn't help. What would be the best way to plot slice over slice of the same `df`?

For example, I want to plot "iter 1" and then plot "iter 2" and "iter 3" over it.

```
for loop through dataframe: 0
0     332    4.6030    91.204062
3     332    9.1985    76.212943
6     332   14.4405    77.664282
9     332   20.2005    76.725955
12    332   25.4780    31.597510
15    332   30.6670    74.096975

for loop through dataframe: 1
1     445    5.4280    60.233917
4     445    9.7345    31.902842
7     445   14.6015    36.261851
10    445   19.8630    40.705467
13    445   24.9050     4.897008
16    445   30.0550    35.217889

for loop through dataframe: 2
2     999    4.6030    91.474156
5     999    9.1985    76.212943
8     999   14.4405    77.664282
11    999   20.2005    76.725955
14    999   25.4780    31.597510
17    999   30.6670    74.096975
```

My entire dataframe looks something like this:

```
0     332    4.6030    91.204062
3     332    9.1985    76.212943
6     332   14.4405    77.664282
9     332   20.2005    76.725955
12    332   25.4780    31.597510
15    332   30.6670    74.096975
1     445    5.4280    60.233917
4     445    9.7345    31.902842
7     445   14.6015    36.261851
10    445   19.8630    40.705467
13    445   24.9050     4.897008
16    445   30.0550    35.217889
2     999    4.6030    91.474156
5     999    9.1985    76.212943
8     999   14.4405    77.664282
11    999   20.2005    76.725955
14    999   25.4780    31.597510
17    999   30.6670    74.096975
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use **[`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)**, which automatically reuses the existing axes:

```
for label, data in df.groupby('S/N'):
    plt.plot(data['Dis'], data['Rate'], label=label)

plt.xlabel('Dis')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.legend()
```

Or use **[`ax.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html)** by first creating `ax` via **[`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)**:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for label, data in df.groupby('S/N'):
    ax.plot(data['Dis'], data['Rate'], label=label)

ax.set(xlabel='Dis', ylabel='Rate')
plt.legend()
```

Or use **[`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)** with `hue='S/N'`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='Dis', y='Rate', hue='S/N', data=df)
```

(Note that I slightly modified some `999` values since they were identical to `332`'s values.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you again, Tdy! I was suprised when I saw the appropriate column names, but then I realised you answered my earlier question as well.